# How to export specific portions of a psd or jpg file?

Tags: photoshop

I have bought graphics from a graphics designer. He gave me a psd file with buttons and logos all in the same file. In the file there is a specific button I want to use for my project. How would I export only the button portion of the file to a png or jpeg?

Answer (score 0):

using the eyeball toggle buttons on the right-hand panel, hide all elements you don't want

then go file > save as

give it a name and type of file you want to save as

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in order to get just the single button or logo is something like what Miles said, but that might leave you with some extra blank space that you don't want.

1. Turn off all layers you don't want to save.
2. Select the crop tool and crop exactly what you want to save.
3. File - > Save for Web - > Select PNG or JPG  and all other settings
4. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

here a little contribution :

1. calibrate your screen, check your color profile, turn you image in RGB mode or Grayscale (8 or 16 bit). ;)
2. Turn off layer you don't want to save, on windows shortcut "ALT+ left click" on layer eye you want to keep.
3. trim layer with menu/image/trim... Transparent Pixels
4. File / Save for Web / Select PNG-8 check transparency, click "Save..." choose a name and save button.

You can use shortcut for do it much more faster.

Of course you can make a Scripts in Scripts panel for repeat this action many times.

You can use free extension like cutandslice.me for export to different device in one shot.

Best wish.